# How can I set a received props into a state without necessity of specify the state names and props names

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
editRow (props) {
   this.state.index = props.rowIndex
   this.state.id = props.row.id
   this.state.name = props.row.name
}
```

This will fill my state, but i want to fill the state without specify the names

Something like that

```
editRow (props) {
  this.state = { ...props }
},
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: if they have differents names (index vs rowIndex), you can't avoid mapping

Comment: ignoring the index is it possible ? I can remove, the index i'snt necessary on my code